# PHP select dropdown based on row value category id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a parts editor, pretty much you can edit parts description, category they are in, and title.

I have a dropdown that gets the categories that are in the database from a table called **category** it has columns **id** and **cat_name**

I also have a **parts** category, that has the columns **id**, **part_name**, **part_desc** and **part_cat**. the **part_cat** is the category it sits in that has a numerical value.

I am trying to make the selector of dropdown options be selected when the table **category** id matches the table part **part_cat**

I am currently using this as a while.

```
<?php
//GET PART INFORMATION
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM part WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

//GET CATEGORY INFORMATION
$sql_cat = "SELECT * FROM category";
$result_cat = mysql_query($sql_cat);
echo '<option disabled="disabled">-- Select A Category --</option>';

while ($row_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_cat))
{
    //SELECT THE DROPDOWN OPTION THAT MATCHES CAT_ID AND PART_CAT
    if ($row_cat['id'] == $row['part_cat']) { 
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';  
    }
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="' . $row_cat['id'] . '">' . 
          $row_cat['cat_name'] . '</option>';
}

?>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

It is not selecting them at all, but when I change **==** to **!=** it selects all of them.

Comment: What is the actual problem??

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is not selecting them at all, but when I change == to != it selects all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop it selecting all of them change this piece of code so that `$selected` does not remember what it was last set to.

FROM

```
if ($row_cat['id'] == $row['part_cat']) { 
    $selected = 'selected="selected"';  
}
```

TO

```
$selected = ($row_cat['id'] == $row['part_cat']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
```